# Is there automatic live renderer to LaTeX?

Tags: miktex, texworks

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm using MiKTeX and TeXworks.

I am wondering if there is a way that every change in my `.tex` automatically rendered and shown on a display?

Currently I click the typeset button every time and I'm looking for an automatic way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at Overleaf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See: https://v2.overleaf.com

Comment: some systems are available, but it's probably better to learn not to look at the preview so often, even with modern hardware some documents take several seconds or several minutes to generate a new pdf so doing it often just slows you down, better to type a few pages of material and then look what you have, and fix any errors.

Comment: That's what LyX does: https://www.lyx.org

Comment: @AndréC my understanding that lyx is showing a typeset view of the source file not a continuously updated view of the tex rendering?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My nephew used it for his thesis precisely because it allowed him to write very long and complicated equations and to see them as they were written, which saved him a lot of time. I haven't tried LyX, but your comment makes me want to try it to check.

Comment: As stated in a complex document a background compile of every character could eventually frustrate you at the rate of one word per minute. Several editors let you select a phrase or line or paragraph and show you a dvi preview of that area, (but not confirm the section is not going to mess up downstream) with small files in a fast machine its only seconds to test that full compile works with a new section. If you want word like system there is bakomatex or popular LyX but compatibility of TeXport /import with others may be a limiting factor. The key is always to test compile as you go along.

Comment: Gummi can show a preview every 1--60 seconds, or after 1--60 seconds of editor inactivity. Said that, this could be a great feature to test  a small like a letter but a pain for big documents like a thesis.  BTW, LyX does **not** do that. Although nearly is a WYSIWYG editor in the maths mode,  is far of show a true preview automatically.

Comment: I'm a fan of Gummi but you should try looking at the various IDEs [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) to see if there are others that work better for you.